Not detecting objects in portrait but only in landscape
I'm working on an iOS app where I replaced the pre-trained object detection model in Apple's Breakfast Finder app with my own model. I trained my model using YOLOv8 from Ultralytics and exported it to the .mlmodel format. It is for detecting the monuments.
The app is detecting objects correctly, but only when the phone is in landscape mode (home button on the right, phone orientation facing left). When the phone is in portrait or any other orientation, the detection does not work correctly.
this is the landscape detection. I want it to detect the same way but in portrait
Here are some details about my setup:
Project: Modified version of Apple's Breakfast Finder app
Model: Custom-trained YOLOv8 model exported to .mlmodel
Frameworks used: Vision, Core ML, AVFoundation
the relevant code section for setting up the camera capture and handle the orientation is
func updateLayerGeometry() {
    let bounds = rootLayer.bounds
    var scale: CGFloat

    let xScale: CGFloat = bounds.size.width / bufferSize.height
    let yScale: CGFloat = bounds.size.height / bufferSize.width

    scale = fmax(xScale, yScale)
    if scale.isInfinite {
        scale = 1.0
    }
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)

    // Rotate the layer into screen orientation and scale and mirror
    detectionOverlay.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)).scaledBy(x: scale, y: -scale))
    // Center the layer
    detectionOverlay.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

    CATransaction.commit()
}

public func exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation() -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
    let curDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    let exifOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation

    switch curDeviceOrientation {
    case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
        exifOrientation = .left
    case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
        exifOrientation = .upMirrored
    case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
        exifOrientation = .down
    case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait:            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
        exifOrientation = .up
    default:
        exifOrientation = .up
    }
    return exifOrientation
}

this is the code for the model integration and deteciton:
/*
See LICENSE folder for this sample’s licensing information.

Abstract:
Contains the object recognition view controller for the Breakfast Finder.
*/

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision
import CoreML

class VisionObjectRecognitionViewController: ViewController {
    
    private var detectionOverlay: CALayer! = nil
    
    // Vision parts
    private var requests = [VNRequest]()
    
    @discardableResult
    func setupVision() -> NSError? {
        // Setup Vision parts
        let error: NSError! = nil
        guard let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "secondbest", withExtension: "mlmodelc") else {
            print("model not loaded")
            return NSError(domain: "VisionObjectRecognitionViewController", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Model file is missing"])
        }
        do {
            let visionModel = try VNCoreMLModel(for: MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL))
            let objectRecognition = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel, completionHandler: { (request, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    // perform all the UI updates on the main queue
                    if let results = request.results {
                        self.drawVisionRequestResults(results)
                    }
                })
            })
            self.requests = [objectRecognition]
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Model loading went wrong: \(error)")
        }
        
        return error
    }
    
    func drawVisionRequestResults(_ results: [Any]) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        detectionOverlay.sublayers = nil // remove all the old recognized objects
        for observation in results where observation is VNRecognizedObjectObservation {
            guard let objectObservation = observation as? VNRecognizedObjectObservation else {
                continue
            }
            // Select only the label with the highest confidence.
            let topLabelObservation = objectObservation.labels[0]
            let objectBounds = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(objectObservation.boundingBox, Int(bufferSize.width), Int(bufferSize.height))
            
            let shapeLayer = self.createRoundedRectLayerWithBounds(objectBounds)
            
            let textLayer = self.createTextSubLayerInBounds(objectBounds,
                                                            identifier: topLabelObservation.identifier,
                                                            confidence: topLabelObservation.confidence)
            shapeLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
            detectionOverlay.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        }
        self.updateLayerGeometry()
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    
    override func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            return
        }
        
        let exifOrientation = exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation()
        
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation, options: [:])
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(self.requests)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    override func setupAVCapture() {
        super.setupAVCapture()
        
        // setup Vision parts
        setupLayers()
        updateLayerGeometry()
        setupVision()
        
        // start the capture
        startCaptureSession()
    }
    
    func setupLayers() {
        detectionOverlay = CALayer() // container layer that has all the renderings of the observations
        detectionOverlay.name = "DetectionOverlay"
        detectionOverlay.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                                         y: 0.0,
                                         width: bufferSize.width,
                                         height: bufferSize.height)
        detectionOverlay.position = CGPoint(x: rootLayer.bounds.midX, y: rootLayer.bounds.midY)
        rootLayer.addSublayer(detectionOverlay)
    }
    
    func updateLayerGeometry() {
        let bounds = rootLayer.bounds
        var scale: CGFloat
        
        let xScale: CGFloat = bounds.size.width / bufferSize.height
        let yScale: CGFloat = bounds.size.height / bufferSize.width
        
        scale = fmax(xScale, yScale)
        if scale.isInfinite {
            scale = 1.0
        }
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        
        // rotate the layer into screen orientation and scale and mirror
        detectionOverlay.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)).scaledBy(x: scale, y: -scale))
        // center the layer
        detectionOverlay.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        CATransaction.commit()
        
    }
    
    func createTextSubLayerInBounds(_ bounds: CGRect, identifier: String, confidence: VNConfidence) -> CATextLayer {
        let textLayer = CATextLayer()
        textLayer.name = "Object Label"
        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String(format: "\(identifier)\nConfidence:  %.2f", confidence))
        let largeFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 10.0)!
        formattedString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: largeFont], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: identifier.count))
        textLayer.string = formattedString
        textLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.height - 10, height: bounds.size.width - 10)
        textLayer.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        textLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        textLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
        textLayer.foregroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0])
        textLayer.contentsScale = 1.0 // retina rendering
        // rotate the layer into screen orientation and scale and mirror
        textLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)).scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0))
        return textLayer
    }
    
    func createRoundedRectLayerWithBounds(_ bounds: CGRect) -> CALayer {
        let shapeLayer = CALayer()
        shapeLayer.bounds = bounds
        shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        shapeLayer.name = "Found Object"
        shapeLayer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 0.2, 0.4])
        shapeLayer.cornerRadius = 7
        return shapeLayer
    }
    
}

I changed the exifOrientation just in case if that would work. but the labels are now being displayed vertically. I was expecting it to detect in portrait. this is the dsplay after i changed the exifOrientation shown in the code :
  public func exifOrientationFromDeviceOrientation() -> CGImagePropertyOrientation {
        let curDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
        let exifOrientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation
        
        switch curDeviceOrientation {
        case UIDeviceOrientation.portraitUpsideDown:  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
            exifOrientation = .up
        case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft:       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
            exifOrientation = .rightMirrored
        case UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight:      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
            exifOrientation = .left
        case UIDeviceOrientation.portrait:            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
            exifOrientation = .right
        default:
            exifOrientation = .right
        }
        return exifOrientation
    }

